# JavaFX ListView with different enums

Tags: java, listview, javafx, enums, mvvmfx

I'm trying to use different type of enums in the same ListView.

I got interface for enums

```
public interface Item {
    int getId();
    String getName();
}
```

Then I create enum

```
public enum Items1 implements Item {
    Item1(1, "Item1"),
    Item2(2, "Item2");
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // Overridden getters from interface.
}
```

I have view with ListView.

```
class SimpleView {
    private ListView<Items1> items;

    public void initialize() {
        items.setItems(viewModel.getItems());
    }
}
```

This code works only with Items1 enums elements of course.

Then I create a second enum

```
public enum Items2 implements Item {
    TestItem(123, "TEST"),
    DevItem(321, "DEV");
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // Overridden getters from interface.
}
```

Is there any way to load depending on some condition elements from two different enums to the same ListView?

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Wouldn’t `private ListView<Item> items;` work?

Answer (score 0):

A custom ListCell should allow you to specify what should be displayed in each cell based on some condition. See https://www.turais.de/how-to-custom-listview-cell-in-javafx/ and [JavaFX using a custom listcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896079/javafx-using-a-custom-listcell) for some direction.